If $M$ is a martingale w.r.t filtration $(F_n)_n$, then $M$ is also a Martingale w.r.t the foltration generated by $M$.
I stumbled upon the following corrolary:
If $M$ is a martingale w.r.t filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$, then $M$ is also a Martingale w.r.t the filtration generated by $M$, $\mathcal{\hat{F}}_n=\sigma(M_n):=(M_n,...,M_n)$ for $n \leq 0$.
It is mentioned that this is a simple consequence of the properties of martingales, but I wasn't able to show this statement.
So my question is, how does one prove this?

Some properties are trivial: that $M_i$ is integrable for each $i$ and that $M_i$ is $\widehat{\mathcal F}_{i}$-measurable.
The only remaining thing is to show that $\mathbb E\left[M_n\mid\widehat{\mathcal F}_{n-1}\right]=M_{n-1}$. Since $ M_{n-1}$ is $\widehat{\mathcal F}_{n-1}$-measurable, this is equivalent to show that
$\mathbb E\left[M_n-M_{n-1}\mid\widehat{\mathcal F}_{n-1}\right]=0$. This follows from the fact that $\widehat{\mathcal F}_{n-1}\subset \mathcal F_{n-1}$ and that $\mathbb E\left[M_n-M_{n-1}\mid \mathcal F_{n-1}\right]=0$.
